# make_unique, factory method or different design for client API?

Tags: c++, c++11, creation-pattern

We have a library with that publishes an abstract base class:

(illustrative psudocode)

---

**/include/reader_api.hpp**

```
class ReaderApi
{
public:
  static std::unique_ptr <ReaderApi> CreatePcapReader ();
  virtual ~ReaderApi() = 0;
};
```

In the library implementation, there is a concrete implementation of `ReaderApi` that reads pcap files:

**/lib/pcap_reader_api.cpp**

```
class PcapReaderApi
: 
  public ReaderApi
{
public:
  ReaderApi() {};
};
```

---

Client code is expected to instantiate one of these `PcapReaderApi` objects via the factory method:

```
std::unique_ptr <ReaderApi> reader = ReaderApi::CreatePcapReader ();
```

This feels gross to me on a couple of levels.

First, the factory method should be free, not a `static` member of `ReaderApi`.  It was made a `static` member of `ReaderApi` to be explicit about the namespaces.  I can see pros & cons either way.  Feel free to comment on this, but it's not my main point of contention.

Second, my instinct tells me I should be using `std::make_unique` rather than calling a factory method at all.  But since the actual object being made is an implementation detail, not part of the public headers, there's nothing for the client to `make_unique`.

The simplest solution, in terms of understandability and code maintenance, appears to be the solution I've already come up with above, unless there is a better solution that I'm not already aware of.  Performance is a not a major consideration here since, because of the nature of this object, it will only be instantiate once, at startup-time.

With code clarity, understandability, and maintainability in mind, is there a better way to design the creation of these objects than I have here?

---

I have considered two alternatives that I'll go over below.

One alternative I've considered is passing in some kind of identifier to a generic `Create` function.  The identifier would specify the kind of object the client wishes to construct.  It would likely be an `enum class`, along these lines:

```
enum class DeviceType
{ 
  PcapReader
};

std::unique_ptr <ReaderApi> CreateReaderDevice (DeviceType);
```

But I'm not sure I see the point of doing this versus just making the create function free and explicit:

```
std::unique_ptr <ReaderApi> CreatePcapReader ();
```

I also thought about specifying the `DeviceType` parameter in `ReaderApi`'s constructor:

```
class ReaderApi
{
public:
  ReaderApi (DeviceType type);
  virtual ~ReaderApi() = 0;
};
```

This would enable the `make_unique` idiom:

```
std::unique_ptr <ReaderApi> reader = std::make_unique <ReaderApi> (DeviceType::PcapReader);
```

But this obviously would present a big problem -- you're actually trying to construct a `ReaderApi`, not a `PcapReader`.  The obvious solution to this problem is to implement a `virtual constructor` idiom or use factory construction.  But virtual construction seems over-engineered to me for this use.

Comment: I am not sure what the question really is. Don't you like the fact that the factory is implemented as a static method? Or, you don't like the factory pattern?

Comment: If we had partial specialization for function-templates, things would be simple...

Comment: @BЈовић Having the factory as a static method kind of breaks the factory pattern in a fundamental way: The base class, which provides the factory method has to know about the concrete class in order to implement the factory. This is often undesirable and may defeat the purpose of having a factory in the first place.

Comment: @BЈовић:  Sorry, I know that I prattled on a bit and I was likely being vague.  My problem is that my concerns are also vague.  I mean this thing works, but just "feels wrong" to me.  I was hoping for some insight that lead me to a solution that didn't "feel wrong."

Comment: Right now I'm thinking that a decent and simple solution is to just put all this stuff in headers.  That would obviate the need for the factory in the first place.  It would also mean that I could only use C++03 stuff in the implementation, but that's not that big of a deal to me.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the solution you have. Given the choice, I'd make `CreatePcapReader()` a free function in the same namespace as `ReaderApi()`. As for not using `make_unique`, the reason we preach using it in the first place is to avoid the use of `new` in user code, and to avoid having raw owning pointers lying around even for a short while, and you've already achieved all that. If it makes you feel better, you could rename the factory function `make_unique_pcap_reader()` :)

Comment: I fully agree with @Praetorian. In particular, there is no benefit from using `make_unique` (unlike `make_shared`). However, whether or not the factory function is best free or a static member of the base depends IMHO the supposed use case. A free function would be the choice for the plug-in pattern, when the plug-in .so file provides its own factory function. In all other situations, I'd prefer the static member to base, as it shows clearly the purpose and the relation to the base.

Comment: Isn't this question *primarily opinion-based*?

Comment: @ComicSansMS The only thing that is WTF here is : why the base class implements the factory method? Shouldn't there be a separate factory class?

Comment: @BЈовић:  That's also a possibility.

Comment: @BЈовић My thoughts exactly. Just didn't want to put it that drastically :)

Comment: @Walter: Not if we limit the scope to technical ramifications of different approaches.  My opinion is based on the technical aspects anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the two options to consider are your current approach, or a namespace level appropriately named free function. There doesn't seem to be a need for an enumerated factory unless there are details you aren't mentioned.

Using `make_unique` is exposing implementation details so I would definitely not suggest that approach.